# How do we deal with Gribov ambiguities when calculating in quantum gauge theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, specific-reference, gauge-theory

How do we deal with [Gribov ambiguities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gribov_ambiguity) when actually calculating in quantum gauge theories? Any literature references?

Answer (score 2):

The problem of Gribov ambiguities is still unsolved.

Please see the following [two](http://www.dft.if.uerj.br/particular/Sorella/gribov/gribov_pendulumf.pdf) [expositions](http://www.dft.if.uerj.br/particular/Sorella/gribov/gribov_horizonf.pdf) by Sobreiro snd Sorella.

Although much is known on the topology of the Gribov copies, the full implications on the theory predictions are not known.

However, progress has been achieved in restricting the configuration space to the interior of the Gribov's horizon, which is not free from Gribov copies (thus does not solve the problem completely).

This restriction results a no-pole condition for the gluon propagator hinting that the Gribov problem is important to the infra-red behavior.

A local action for yang-Mills theories inside the first Gribov horison was obtained by Zwanziger. This action was used mainly in Lattice simulations.

Comment: +1, thanks for the links, but it is good to note in a pedagogical context that it doesn't arise in lattice regularization.